# Suitable diagramming type and tool for a model based on DevExpress Domain Components

Tags: uml, devexpress, modeling, xaf

I'm busy prototyping a training management app using the [DevExpress eXpressApp framework & Domain Components](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ThirdParty/DomainComponentsInXAF_1.aspx). This paradigm uses interfaces to specify domain entities, with default implementation logic generated at runtime, so that I can effectively enjoy multiple inheritance in my business entities.

I'm curious as to what sort of diagram I could use here to communicate my design assumptions to my client, without requiring me to build and deploy too frequently merely to confirm my assumptions etc. Hopefully fellow SO users familiar with this framework and it being used like I am doing can shed some light on this.

Comment: I don't know "DevExpress eXpressApp" so maybe that answers my question already, but: What aspects of your design do you want to express with the diagram(s)? Class structure?

Comment: Yes, but not 'physical' class structure. Sorry, I meant to include a link to 'DevExpress eXpressApp', but in it a *domain component* model is defined only by interfaces, with implementer classes being generated at runtime. I have added a link now.

Comment: ok, what's wrong with class diagrams then? They don't need a 'physical' class.

Comment: @Christian, looks like I'll end up using just class diagrams, but I will have to manually map interface/logic combos in code to classes in the diagram. Not ideal, but it won't kill me.

Comment: If you literally need to "communicate my design assumptions to my client", probably a class diagram will be really sufficient for you. And there is no need to invent anything for plugging domain logics, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I felt that your question is a duplicate to [Design and Modeling for DexExpress eXpressApp Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793459/design-and-modelling-for-dexexpress-expressapp-framework). Basically, you will be able to model individual domain components using built-in Visual Studio modeling tools. It works pretty well with interfaces. Probably, you can also build a custom modeling solution based on an open source [Liekhus ADO.NET Entity Data Model XAF Extensions](http://efxaf.codeplex.com/) tool. 
Finally, since you are using XAF (and I believe you are also a DevExpress customer),  I suggest you contact our [Support Team](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) to get fast and guaranteed assistance on XAF or any other DevExpress products.

Comment: It isn't a duplicate. In my other question I ask about the modelling processes and methods suitable for a XAF application. Here I'm asking about tools to communicate the structure of a XAF application, where the modelling process is basically complete. 

The Liekhus tool looks fascinating and useful though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can model with a class diagram but what is generated at run time can not be modeled. I mean that for example if you have a model then you use the Model Driven Development in order to generate a code from your model then the generated code is not anymore your model but only the code like your run time classes.

Hope this help.